# How to resolve duplicate entry: com/google/gson/Gson$5.class

Tags: android, duplicates, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am working on android project in which I am trying to make a Signed APK. I am not getting any error in code or for any missing library, my project is also running fine. But when I am trying to make SIGNED APK with it, I am getting the following error:

```
duplicate entry: com/google/gson/Gson$5.class
```

My Gradle is given below. I have followed different answers from this forum, but still getting the problem.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.0'

    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'

    compile 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:2.0.0'
    // If you want to use the GPU Filters
    compile 'jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage:gpuimage-library:1.3.0'


    //compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
//    compile project(':uImageLoader')
    //compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')

    compile 'cn.trinea.android.common:trinea-android-common:4.2.15'

    // IO Library used for Files
    compile ('com.octo.android.robospice:robospice-retrofit:1.4.13') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.commons', module: 'commons-io'
    }
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:1.3.2'


    compile project(':ParseUI-Login')
    compile rootProject.ext.androidSupport
    compile rootProject.ext.parse

}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    repositories
    dependencies {
        // TODO: move this to a stable release as soon as one becomes available
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.fourbong"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 4
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
       // android.enforceUniquePackageName=false
    }


        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/maven/commons-io/commons-io/pom.xml'
            exclude 'META-INF/maven/commons-io/commons-io/pom.properties'
        }


   repositories
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
```

Comment: why you add  compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1' this twice?

Comment: @Dipalishah by mistake i wrote it there, i removed it. But still i am getting a same problem for Duplication gson.

Comment: Unrelated but still error: Remove support-v4. a) The version does not match appcompat-v7. b) Appcompat-v7 depends on support-v4 so it's included anyway. c) Why do you exclude support libraries at the end? The app will crash when you finally manage to run it.

Comment: if you have put the jar in your libs, remove it

Answer (score 0):

you add

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.0'
```

compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1' this two times remove any one and rebuild project

Comment: If you add the exact same thing twice it has no effect. Besides I highly doubt glide depends on gson.

Comment: @EugenPechanec , yup it doesn't depend on GSON in any way